# Plotting shapes in python

Tags: python-3.x, shapefile

I have a shapefile from GADM that has a lot of polygons showing the states and provinces of Colombia, but I'm only interested in one of them. Is it possible to extract this one polygon and plot it afterwards using python3?

Comment: Hey Nailuj, extarct it how? Plot it how? What features does this shapefile got?

Comment: Hi,

The shapefile I'm working on, when plotted, looks like this: 
https://gadm.org/maps/COL.html (select the "show sub-divisions" button). Each province is a polygon that has a geometry associated. In my case I don't want to plot all the provinces but one, but I don't know how to extract a certain polygon or geometry from the shapefile and plot it independently. 
The shapefile I'm using is made out of 6 other files with the extensions .cpg, .dbf, .prj, .shp and .shx.

Comment: Based on what you say, seems to me that you are new to the use of shapefiles. Those other files (cpg dbf ...) are complements to the .shp file. The minimum files you will need are three: .shp, .shx, and .dbf.... others are optional. I suggest you first explore your shapefile, to see if it has (most likely) different features and which columns they have (so you can filter by those values). Without having the actual shapefile we can't help you do that. If you want, go ahead and do so (with qgis, or other tools) and then come back to clarify your shapefile's structure